# Is it possible to add a covariate (control for a variable of no interest) to an SVM model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm very new to machine learning and python and I'm trying to build a model to predict patients (N=200) vs controls (N=200) form structural neuroimaging data. After the initial preprocessing were I reshaped the neuroimaging data into a 2D array I built the following model:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc = SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear')


from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from numpy import range
k_range = np.arange(0.1,10,0.1)
param_grid=dict(C=k_range)
grid=GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(img,labels)
grid.grid_scores_
print grid.best_score_
print grid.best_params_
```

This gives me a decent a result but I'd like to control for the fact that different images were acquired with different scanners (e.g. subjects 1 through 150 were scanned with scanner 1, subjects 101 through 300 were scanned with scanner 2 and subjects 301 through 400 were scanned with scanner 3). Is there anyway this could be added to the model above?

I read that doing a previous feature selection might help. However, I don't want to simply extract meaningful features when those features might be related to the scanner. In fact, I want to classify patients and controls NOT based on the scanner (i.e. controlling for scanner).

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated,
thank you

Comment: Just a comment, the grid the for parameter `C` should be log spaced. `k_range = np.logspace(-1, 1, 100)`

Comment: Thank you @ZichenWang for your suggestion, will updated the code.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're looking for some form of normalization, where scanner error is abstracted away. I'm not sure what the methods are, but maybe the broader term might help.

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosCoto I'll read a bit more on normalization and how it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diagnostics, you could take a look at how your data is distributed per scanner to see whether this direction you're pursuing is promising. Normalization (e.g., of mean+variance per scanner) can be one option as someone already suggested. Another option is adding 3 additional dimensions to your feature set as a one-hot encoding for the scanner used (i.e., for each example, you have a 1 in the position of the appropriate scanner and 0 for others)

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. I quite like the last option you mentioned. I'll definitely give it go.

Answer (score 0):

To add it to your model, you can your your normalization parameter for each scanner as a feature and include it in your model.

Comment: Explain your answer well