# Add covariates to classification task in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

For my project, I want to build a classifier that predicts the class of my subjects (patients vs. healthy controls) based on a feature set of voxel values from structural MRI data. I use `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` as a classifier. Since age and gender have an effect on voxel intensities in sMRI data, I would like to include them as covariates in my classification task. How can I do this in scikit-learn? Do I just add them to my feature set? If yes, how do I deal with the different scales of the covariates (age is continuous, gender is categorical)?

Here's a simply dummy example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# dummy feature set (columns represent voxels)
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

# dummy labels (1 = patients, 0= healthy controls)
y = np.array([1,0,1,0])

# dummy covariates (age and gender) - These should be included in my classification task
age = np.array([18,25,31,55])
gender = np.array([1,1,0,0])

# z-standardize features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# classification task
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=rng)
lr.fit(X, y)
predictions = lr.predict(X)
```

This post might be related to an [earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277647/is-it-possible-to-add-a-covariate-control-for-a-variable-of-no-interest-to-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my neuroimaging predictive models I usually build 2 models. One with the data of interest and another one including age etc. If performance does not change significantly then the age etc do not contribute to the predictive ability of the data.

Of course, you should use a cross-validation scheme for these type of questions.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# dummy feature set (columns represent voxels)
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

# dummy labels (1 = patients, 0= healthy controls)
y = np.array([1,0,1,0])

# dummy covariates (age and gender) - These should be included in my classification task
age = np.array([18,25,31,55])
gender = np.array([1,1,0,0])

Xfull = np.concatenate([X,age.reshape(-1,1),gender.reshape(-1,1)], axis = 1)

# z-standardize features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# z-standardize features with covariates 
scaler2 = StandardScaler()
Xfull = scaler2.fit_transform(Xfull)


# classification task - model 1
lr1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=rng)
lr1.fit(X, y)
print("Score using only voxel data: {}".format(lr.score(X,y)))

# classification task - model 2
lr2 = LogisticRegression(random_state=rng)
lr2.fit(Xfull, y)
print("Score using voxel data & covariates: {}".format(lr2.score(Xfull,y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this means, I just add them to my feature set. I don't have to treat age and gender differently from my voxel values, although gender will be the only categorical feature in my dataset? I thought that I have to treat gender differently when I standardize the data.

Comment: In any case the same standardization should be applied to all features. Before that you might want to transform the categorical variable first